# MySQL 'AND' not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM students 
WHERE gwid NOT IN (
    SELECT gwid FROM attendance 
    WHERE((date='160126') AND (classid = 'm1100'))
)
```

The query runs without an error but it still shows rows in which the classid is not m1100. Please look at the same result below:

[image]

Comment: For the last row, does the other constraint (`Date`) hold as well?

Comment: Have you tried removing the parenthesis in the were clause of your subquery ?

Comment: Nulls can mess up a `not in` although it doesn't appear `gwid` is nullable here.

Comment: Are you wanting to exclude rows where either of the conditions match or both of them?

Comment: Please specify what you expect to get from the query?

Comment: If i understand well, you want all the student that did not attend the class m1100 at the date '160126'

Answer (score 0):

You said you wanted to get the classid m1100 so you should delete the not keyword. Also, the parenthesis in the where clause of the subquery are not needed but I don't know if it changes anything. Also, I think you need to filter on the classid in the outer query to avoid getting students with a guid in the subquery results that are not in classId m1100.

Try this :

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  students 
WHERE 
  gwid 
IN      
  (SELECT 
     gwid 
   FROM 
     attendance
   WHERE 
     date='160126' 
   AND 
     classid = 'm1100')
AND 
  classId = 'm1100'
```

Comment: Why does this slove the problem? explain the answer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM students as x 
WHERE gwid NOT IN (
    SELECT gwid FROM attendance
    WHERE date='160126' AND classid = x.classid ) 
AND x.classid = 'm1100'
```

well... first off you are after of classid = m1100 but you wanted gwids not in the attendance for that particular class id... so your subquery should be limited to the classid from the main query classid

Comment: then edit your answer to add the explanation (P.S. I'm not OP)

Answer (score 0):

Your AND is working just fine, but you're asking to see students who did not attend that class on that specific date only. If you ment to filter out all students who did not attend that class, you should omit your date-clause in the sub-select.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to apply a plain English interpretation to the query and you're seeking to find students who were *not in* attendance in that class on that date?

To do that you would need to know which students were supposed to be in class that day so you'd need some kind of enrollment information. This is probably a total stab in the dark. Note that I'm assuming that `gwid` is a student identifier and that you have some kind of enrollment/registration source to sit between students and attendance.

```
SELECT *
FROM students
WHERE gwid in
(
    SELECT gwid
    FROM enrollment
    WHERE classid = 'm1100' and gwid NOT IN
    (
        SELECT gwid
        FROM attendance
        WHERE date = '160126' AND classid = 'm1100'
    )
)
```

For various reasons you might prefer or need to avoid repeating the `classid` argument:

```
/* Modified to avoid repeating the classid */
SELECT *
FROM students
WHERE gwid IN
(
    SELECT gwid
    FROM enrollment e
    WHERE classid = 'm1100' and gwid NOT IN
    (
        SELECT gwid
        FROM attendance a
        WHERE a.classid = e.classid AND date = '160126'
    )
)
```

Some people object to cascaded `in` subqueries. There's certainly a strong case for learning how to write a SQL join:

```
/* Modified to use an inner join */
SELECT *
FROM students s inner join enrollment e on e.gwid = s.gwid
WHERE e.classid = 'm1100' and e.gwid NOT IN (
        SELECT gwid
        FROM attendance a
        WHERE a.classid = e.classid AND date = '160126'
    )
```

And it's possible to eliminate the `not in` as well although the join condition is more complicated and I would probably just stick with one of the previous queries. I think this construction is more familiar to developers now than it used to be.

```
/* Modified to use a left join */
SELECT *
FROM
    students s
    inner join enrollment e
        on e.gwid = s.gwid
    left outer join attendance a
        on a.classid = e.classid and a.gwid = e.gwid and a.date = '160126'
WHERE
    e.classid = 'm1100' and a.gwid is null
```